# WS FEDERATION AUTHENTICATION MODULE Signout in ASPNET not clearing/expiring session cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, session-cookies, okta, ws-federation

According to documentations- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.services.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.signout?view=netframework-4.8#System_IdentityModel_Services_WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SignOut_System_Boolean_ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.services.sessionauthenticationmodule.signout?view=netframework-4.8  should clear all the sessions in application. But after calling WSFederationAuthenticationModule .SignOut(true) and SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut() those session still remains valid. I am using .NET Framework 4.5.

[image: SecureFedAuthCookieWebConfig]
[image: WS FED sign in]
[image: SameSiteCookieWebConfig]
[image: Logout]
[image: FedAuthCookiesNotClearedAfterSignOut]
To make cookie configuration SameSite=none the cookies must be made secure which we have done in Web.config file. But the WS Fed Authentication Sign out is not clearing the sessions as per the documentations. Reference- https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/FAQ-How-Chrome-80-Update-for-SameSite-by-default-Potentially-Impacts-Your-Okta-Environment.

I think this is due to buggy WS FED module by .NET Framework. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help others out with this same problem.

You have to change the "No SameSite" rule to also check for the "secure" flag. Like this:

```
<add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; secure" />
```

This is because WSFederation will do the clearing of the cookies without adding the secure flag and without the secure flag, chrome ignores the set cookie request to clear the cookies.

You don't need to do anything else, like clear/set the cookies manually, just use the SignOut() method provided by the WSFederationAuthenticationModule.